# Java EE authentification process

Tags: java, spring, http, jakarta-ee

I'm a beginner in Java EE programming and I'm trying to make my first web application.

Here is what I'm trying to find out:

- I understand how to use the HttpSession object to start a session after verifying username and password
- After this process should I verify (make a test (if)) in every protected page (*jsp file that only authenticated user can access*)?
- Is there any easier way to do this, or should I test in every page that a session is up and if not redirect the person to an authentication page?

Comment: There is a component called Filter - that should help.

Comment: you should use spring security to authenticate a user that way once they are authenticated you won't need to run tests on each jsp page, spring will do it for you. Here is the documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.html

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the native Servlet API, you should make a `Filter` class, and declare it as a `WebFilter` in your `web.xml`, or using the `@WebFilter` annotation.

In it, you should check a few a things:

- if the page is not protected, then do nothing, simply call the next filter in the chain (`chain.doFilter(request, response);`)
- if the page is protected check for authentication:

  - if it checks out, call the next item of the chain
  - if not, redirect to the login page (or whatever else you want to)

There is a complete [tutorial here](http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial).

Of course, you might also use frameworks to do this for you, and also some application servers provide authentication solutions. But if you are really a beginner, I advise you to at least try the "plain old" solution.